# biomaRt: Cannot access the zebra fish dataset

Tags: r, biomart

I cannot access the zebra fish ensembl database with biomaRt in R...

```
# biomaRt
library (biomaRt)

listMarts()

ensembl <- useMart("ensembl")

listDatasets(ensembl) #output is really bad, with huge spaces between lines (cannot copy it here)

listDatasets(ensembl)$dataset
```

Returns

```
 [1] "amelanoleuca_gene_ensembl"  "dordii_gene_ensembl"        "mpahari_gene_ensembl"      
 [4] "trubripes_gene_ensembl"     "pmarinus_gene_ensembl"      "sharrisii_gene_ensembl"    
 [7] "nleucogenys_gene_ensembl"   "ggallus_gene_ensembl"       "olatipes_gene_ensembl"     
[10] "pcoquereli_gene_ensembl"    "pabelii_gene_ensembl"       "mspreteij_gene_ensembl"    
[13] "rroxellana_gene_ensembl"    "jjaculus_gene_ensembl"      "cporcellus_gene_ensembl"   
[16] "mochrogaster_gene_ensembl"  "dmelanogaster_gene_ensembl" "clanigera_gene_ensembl"    
[19] "cfamiliaris_gene_ensembl"   "cchok1gshd_gene_ensembl"    "xtropicalis_gene_ensembl"  
[22] "oniloticus_gene_ensembl"    "dnovemcinctus_gene_ensembl" "sscrofa_gene_ensembl"      
[25] "ecaballus_gene_ensembl"     "mmusculus_gene_ensembl"     "oanatinus_gene_ensembl"    
[28] "tguttata_gene_ensembl"      "fcatus_gene_ensembl"        "amexicanus_gene_ensembl"   
[31] "eeuropaeus_gene_ensembl"    "ccrigri_gene_ensembl"       "sboliviensis_gene_ensembl"
```

Where is the zebra fish database?

```
ensembl = useDataset("drerio_gene_ensembl", mart = ensembl)
```

That returns:

```
Error in useDataset("drerio_gene_ensembl", mart = ensembl) : 
  The given dataset:  drerio_gene_ensembl , is not valid.  Correct dataset names can be obtained with the listDatasets function.
```

While it looks like the correct name (I'm following a tutorial)... What is happening?

Comment: What is output of `listDatasets(ensembl)`

Comment: I edited my answer, was difficult to answer in a comment

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it seems as if biomaRt servers are down (again). The service is quite unreliable, I had similar problems already a couple of months ago.

Comment: Ho really? I had a look on the ensembl website I did not see anything... Anyway around this? It is quite frustrating!

Comment: Hey @romeasy, I also asked my question on Biostars, and Mike Smith came with a patch for the biomaRt version, which worked great for me! Here is it: https://www.biostars.org/p/289145/